# SQLite - Importing csv-files is limited to 1 Mio?

Tags: sqlite, csv, import

I wanted to import 6 Millions rows into an sqlite database. It works fine but the only limitation is that sqlite does only import 1 Mio rows at once. I had to split the csv file into 7 files to import all rows. I tried to import with SQLite Manager (Firefox addon) and from sqlite command-tool. Both import exactly 1 Mio rows. Is there a parameter which I have to change?  
OS: Windows XP and 7, 64 bit
Thanks for hints.

Comment: Fast forward to 2021, and I just imported a 1.3GB CSV file with over 20 million lines using the "in-memory" default, no sweat.

Answer (score 1):

(If I needed this, I would write my own Perl script using [`DBD::CSV`](https://metacpan.org/module/DBD%3a%3aCSV) and [`DBD::SQLite`](https://metacpan.org/module/DBD%3a%3aSQLite) to perform this task.)

If you don't know Perl, you can use **[csv2sqlite](https://metacpan.org/module/App%3a%3acsv2sqlite)** - Perl script that automates this task.

Since you are on Windows, you need to have Perl first - download and install [ActivePerl](http://www.activestate.com/activeperl/downloads). Then, install `csv2sqlite` using `ppm` from command line:

```
ppm install App::csv2sqlite
```

After this, you will have command line utility `csv2sqlite` available, and it should work for CSV data sizes above 1 million rows.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try and report. I have already Strawberry-Perl installed.